# Read and parse perf.data

Tags: linux, performance, parsing, profiling, performancecounter

I am recording a performance counters frm linux using the command perf record.

I want to use the result `perf.data` as an input to other programming apps. Do you know how shall I read and parse the data in `perf.data`? Is there a way to transform it to `.text` file or `.csv`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

An example command definition that redirects service check performance data to a text file for later processing by another application is shown below:

```
define command{

    command_name    store-service-perfdata

    command_line    /bin/echo -e "$LASTSERVICECHECK$\t$HOSTNAME$\t$SERVICEDESC$\t$SERVICESTATE$\t$SERVICEATTEMPT$\t$SERVICESTATETYPE$\t$SERVICEEXECUTIONTIME$\t$SERVICELATENCY$\t$SERVICEOUTPUT$\t$SERVICEPERFDATA$" >> /usr/local/nagios/var/service-perfdata.dat

    }
```

Comment: seems intersting.. can you please elaborate more on how shall I use this piece of code?

Comment: You have to change your nagios configuration for this one so the data gets written in the text file.

Comment: @Yannick, this question is not about nagios, it about `perf` command line tool of linux-tools (`perf_events` subsystem of kernel), which is for application profiling, not for nagios integration or nagios perfdata https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/perfdata.html where performance of ping is considered.

Answer (score 7):

There is builtin `perf.data` parser and printer in `perf` tool of linux tools with subcommand "script".

To convert `perf.data` file

```
perf script > perf.data.txt
```

To convert output of perf record in other file (`perf record -o filename.data`) use `-i` option:

```
perf script -i filename.data > filename.data.txt
```

`perf script` is documented at `man perf-script`, available online at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-script.1.html

> ```
>    perf-script - Read perf.data (created by perf record) and display
>    trace output
>
>    This command reads the input file and displays the trace recorded.
>
>        'perf script' to see a detailed trace of the workload that was
>        recorded.
> ```

Comment: Output of `perf script` is text and is readable, but it may be not easy to parse it with python/perl/awk/something scripts.

Comment: `perf script` specifically allows processing of pref events with python and perl scripts. See [`man perf-script-python`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-script-python.txt)

Answer (score 4):

`perf data convert --to-json` landed in April.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-data.1.html

Comment: any idea if `perf data convert --to-json` also requires building linux with `LIBBABELTRACE=1`. Trying to get this working on an out of the box ubuntu distro.

Comment: `No conversion support compiled in. perf should be compiled with environment variables LIBBABELTRACE=1 and LIBBABELTRACE_DIR=/path/to/libbabeltrace/` in perf `perf version 4.14.336-253.554.amzn2.aarch64`

Answer (score 1):

The `quipper` sub-project of https://github.com/google/perf_data_converter can parse `perf.data` files.