# Filtering perf.data (linux perf profiler) files for time intervals

Tags: linux, performance, filter, profiling, perf

I have output of perf linux profiler (perf_events) in file `perf.data`. This file is result of `perf record ./some_multithreaded_app` or `perf record -a sleep 600`. My application have several kinds of works interleaved: data generation, useful computation on data, some checking of results; with all three stages started many times. My application also prints timestamps between stages (now only with second accuracy, should change it into micro or nanosecond).

When I do normal `perf report`, I have mix of profile results from all stages.

I want to filter events recorded in `perf.data` for some time intervals, when stage two was working, and get output as new `perf.data`-formatted file like `perf.data.loop1.stage2`.

Is it possible to parse events from `perf.data`, apply some simple filter on event timestamp, and output filtered events back into `perf.data` format documented in

- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf.data-file-format.txt
- https://openlab-mu-internal.web.cern.ch/openlab-mu-internal/03_Documents/3_Technical_Documents/Technical_Reports/2011/Urs_Fassler_report.pdf

As my `perf.data` was from several cpu cores, events in the `perf.data` may be out of order (not sorted by timestamps - [perf.data-file-format.txt: "The events are not necessarily in time stamp order"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf.data-file-format.txt))

Comment: There was similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937094 but without complete solution to filter `perf.data` into `perf.data.subinterval`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to narrow down perf.data to a time sub interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937094/how-to-narrow-down-perf-data-to-a-time-sub-interval)  (I added an answer to that question that should have both covered).

Comment: On second thought I'm unsure which question to keep, but as is there is a huge overlap.

Comment: @Zulan, thanks, `--time` option of perf subcommands like [`perf report`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html) may help in my case, when I want to parse result with `perf` tools. And for converting perf.data to FlameGraph there is awk solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937094 too. Do you have knowledge about parsing perf.data or `perf script` output in python/perl/any scripting language - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921842 ?

Comment: `perf script` works very well with python: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-script-python.txt